# How to get polygon data from map in angular2-google-maps?

Tags: angular2-google-maps

I working on this example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
    .sebm-google-map-container {
       height: 300px;
     }
  `],
  template: `
    <sebm-google-map 
      [latitude]="lat"
      [longitude]="lng"
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [disableDefaultUI]="false"
      [zoomControl]="false">

      <sebm-map-polygon 
        [paths]="paths"
        [editable]="true" 
        [draggable]="true" 
        (polyClick)="click(event)" 
        (polyDblClick)="delete(event)">
      </sebm-map-polygon>

    </sebm-google-map>
`})
export class App {
  zoom: number = 8;
  paths : Array<LatLngLiteral>;
  lat: number = 51.673858;
  lng: number = 7.815982;

  click(event: any){
    console.log(event);
  }

  delete(event: any){
    console.log(event);
  }

   paths: Array<LatLngLiteral> = [
      { lat: 51.373858,  lng: 7.815982 },
      { lat: 51.673858,  lng: 7.215982 },
      { lat: 51.373858,  lng: 7.895982 }
    ];
}

http://plnkr.co/edit/8SuDfG6BD0HubpLHqHc8?p=preview
```

but I want to get all polygon data when I click button "save" (in my project).

How to get all polygon data from map?

Comment: 1. It's $event, not event
2. You already have access to this.path.. what more info do you want?